# Delete the Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set instances using Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-runbook

First I want to know if is possible to delete vmss instances based on cpu performance of the instances but not by using scaling.

I have a scale set in which the instances have different cpu average and I want to remove only the instances with the lowest cpu performance, let's say instances with less than 20% cpu performance.

The idea is to make a cycle to pass through all the instances and then a condition where I select all the vmss instances with less than 20% cpu performance. Inside the condition to delete the selected the vmss instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use the automatic scale, it's the best and simplest way to scale the VMSS. If you use the Runbook, you need to get the CPU performance yourself every interval. And I don't know a simple way to get it. You just can easily see the CPU performance in the Azure portal. Go to use the automatic scale, that's the way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know the scaling is the best way but the client insist to use the runbook and his solution has to many instances with different cpu usage. In fact I wanted a second opinion because I am not sure if his approach is possible.

Comment: @Llazar According to my knowledge, it's impossible.

Comment: Thanks Charles, appreciate your help.

Comment: @Llazar That's ok.